# What caused this shadow on Falcon 9 stage 2 w/Jason-3 before circularization burn?

Tags: spacex, low-earth-orbit, upper-stage, payload-deployment

While the image appears bright, the light is just reflected sunlight (from the earth, per the webcast). The circularization burn doesn't start until about T+ 00:55:16 per the SpaceX [webcast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkz_lclGXNg). But at about T+ 00:52:58 it looks like an object produces a moving shadow that passes from left to right across the spacecraft. If so, what was it?

If the shadow is caused by blocking the light from the earth, then this puts constraints on its size.

[image: SpaceX_Jason-3_shadow_GIF cropped quarter speed]

Comment: Its the aliens, they are watching us! [/joke]

Didnt they launch Jason 3 somewhen around that time?

Comment: If someone has some information on the approximate location of the camera, I could start to work out the size of the object based on the shadow. It's bigger than just a tiny shred of mylar film [like these probably are](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/13593/12102), but definitely way smaller than the moon!