# What is the mysterious cube shaped object observed in the Falcon 9 launch?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9

For today's(November 15 2018) Falcon 9 launch, at around `T+ 06:04` into the mission, we can see a cube shaped object flying near to Falcon 9 first stage. This happens just before the first stage reentry.

[image: screenshot of SpaceX's Es’hail-2 Mission]

What this object? The object seems to be in very stable flight.

Comment: Good question! Possibly the fairing.

Comment: I doubt it is fairing, the fairing is separated few seconds after first stage separation and it can't be flying in opposite direction

Comment: May be the shape of the object is a cube, but it may be something very different too. Many more pixels would be necessary to see what it might be.

Comment: @JithinJose The fairing is flying in the same direction, but as it and the first stage begin to hit atmosphere, the fairing decelerates much more rapidly (because it has a lower ratio of mass to cross section), so the first stage could overtake it.

Comment: @RussellBorogove, Assuming fairing is able to decelerate at that high rate(at 60km), we should see fairing going down. But we can see this object is coming from the lower end of the first stage and going up.

Comment: Is there anything else than a fairing that is separated during a successful launch from such a rocket? Something as large as a fairing, no small debris like explosive bolts.

Comment: I spotted this too - I thought maybe with the low quality it is actually quite close and may be a some ice breaking away from the engines and drifting by. I'm confident it can't be the fairings since stage sep occurs around +2:42, but fairing jettison around 1 minute and 300m/s later, putting them on significantly different trajectories.

Comment: I reset the cue time of the video, since they have reposted it with the beginning chunk of screen-saver cut off, which is their standard procedure a day or three after launch. See the answer to [What is it that SpaceX is editing out of their videos after posting them on YouTube?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16776/12102) for more on that.

Answer (score 6):

It's ice. Why? Occam's Razor. At the altitudes the Falcon 9 first stage peaks within there's very little else you would see - there's too much atmosphere to orbit so debris drop rapidly. There's too little atmosphere for any known fauna, and the only man made vehicles that can operate there are things like a launch vehicle - they won't turn up unexpectedly.

Any objects that separated at other times from the vehicle - fairings, for instance - differ too wildly in drag coefficient to remain in proximity with the first stage for more than a few minutes.

The only remaining source of physical objects in the stage's vicinity becomes the stage itself. Since it landed OK and there were no signs of trouble, we can guess it isn't a part of the vehicle. Since the vehicle stores and pumps and vents large quantities of liquid oxygen, we know for certain it will have many deposits of ice, both water ice collecting on outer surfaces as well as solid oxygen forming at vents as decompression rapidly chills the vent output.

The cameras are located near the top of the booster. There is ~40 meters of vehicle below the cameras, lots of room to shed ice out of sight of the camera. As the vehicle falls towards Earth these pieces of ice break free and tumble outward. Their large, thin shape lets them catch the air and slow more rapidly and they come into sight of the camera as they move outward and upward. Tumbling can present many cross sections to the camera, producing unusual shapes.

To the comments doubting the existence of ice at apoapsis - the vehicle clearly remains partly covered in ice throughout the entire mission, as the LOX tankage remains clean of soot after the mission. If all the ice shook free by apoapsis, the retrograde propulsion at the reentry burn as well as the brief exposure to stage two thrust post-staging would deposit kerosene soot on the stage, to be revealed after the ice melts at landing. This image in the hangar indicates the LOX tank remains clean even after presumably melting/drying on land and being transferred to the hangar.

[image: Photo of unwashed, used Falcon 9 booster resting horizontally in the hangar. The lower half to third shows black soot from the engines, with clean cutouts where the legs folded against the body. The middle third is clean white where ice shielded the body from soot, fading back to black/grey at the top where LOX was consumed and no ice remained, partway through the mission.]

Comment: This was my thought process [exactly](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32026/what-is-the-mysterious-cube-shaped-object-observed-in-the-falcon-9-launch#comment97365_32026), but I don't feel we can say anything definitively without better quality footage...

Comment: We're likely seeing the best quality footage available already, or near enough. Absent some other piece of evidence (a problem report from SpaceX indicating the vehicle might have shed debris, or some outside confirmation of anything else operating in the area), I remain really confident in the ice theory.

Comment: If you're suggesting it's ice that came from the first stage, I don't see how it got so far ahead of the stage and then fell back past it. If you're suggesting ice from the second stage, the fairing would be at least as plausible.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I believe the suggestion is the ice broke away from the base of the first stage and drifted back past the camera - I think it appears from behind the stage body rather than coming into view from a distance

Comment: Exactly what Jack said. I'm suggesting ice left the rocket somewhere below the camera and became visible as it drifted outwards and the stage fell past it.

Comment: The stage shown seems to be very high above the clouds at a height about 40 to 80 km. Does ice at the LOX tank stays so long and high?

Comment: @Uwe I’d expect any ice chunk that big to have fallen off very early in flight due to vibration.

Comment: Ice remains on the sides of the tanks long enough to sheild the LOX tank from soot all the way to landing. Plus the second stage is often seen venting oxygen from it's engine camera - first stage likely vents some as well, in the process of recovery.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: I too expect any big ice chunk to have fallen off very early in flight due to vibration. Heat from hypersonic flight will have removed any left ice. The very thin and dry air at high altitudes does not contain much humidity to support fresh ice deposits. Remaining ice will sublimate at very low pressure.

Comment: Edited in an image that I believe supports the assumption the vehicle remains covered (partly) in ice throughout the entire mission.